# Windows narrator not announcing expanded/collapsed state when role="tab".....Accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, microsoft-edge, narrator

Upon clicking the button with appropriate Javascript to toggle aria-expanded property of the button.

Narrator/edge will announce the epanded/collapsed property in every click in this case. Notice role="tab" is missing.

```
<div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
      Nils Frahm
    </button>
    <button aria-expanded="false" tabindex="1">
      Agnes Obel
    </button>
  </div>
```

I need role="tab" and aria-expanded property at the same time. This works fine with Chrome/NVDA but with Narrator/edge combination only the initial state of expand/collapse is announced. In the subsequent click, the narrator is silent.

```
<div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button role="tab"aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
      Nils Frahm
    </button>
    <button role="tab" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="1">
      Agnes Obel
    </button>
  </div>
```

I tried looking for information in the web but there isn't much out there. So, giving this a shot. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean with `role="tab"` Narrator won't tell expand/collapse? I can reproduce the issue. I also test it in Chrome with Narrator and the result seems to be the same. Maybe it's the different behavior with different screen readers. I think you can provide feedback to Narrator about this issue through Feedback Hub.